# Python: when should you use subclasses instead of methods?

Tags: python, class, methods, subclass

Let's say I'm trying to make a class of two search algorithms, binary search and linear search. The way I see it there are three ways to do this.

Option 1: Make a class `Search()` with two methods `binary_search` and `linear_search`. The search algorithm would then depend on which method a user chooses to use. Example: the user would create the object `s = Search()` followed by usage of `s.binary_search()`.

Option 2: Make a class `Search()` with a method `do_search` that calls on two private methods `_binary_search` and `_linear_search` based on what 
value is passed to an `__init__` argument. Example: the user would create the object `b = Search('binary')`.

Option 3: Make a base class `Search()` with two subclasses `Binary()` and `Linear()`. The user would then choose an algorithm by using the appropriate subclass. Example: the user would create the object `b = Binary()`.

My question is which one of the three options should you use and why?

I think from a design perspective Option 3 is best, but I'm not really sure why. And I am interested about other perspectives as well (not just design).

Comment: It doesn't seem like any of these classes are adding anything useful. Why not write two functions and no classes?

Comment: I wanted to use a simple example so my question would be easy to understand. I think the overall question/concept is still valid however, even if  it can be done with just functions in this case. Distinguishing among the three options will allow for identifying the best option for when you actually do need a class structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be using classes at all in this particular case, because there is no saved state. Remember, classes are useful for grouping data together with methods that operate on that data. But in a binary search, there is no data. What I mean is, you get some input (the list), and you do some computation on that input to produce some output (an index), and then you return the output, and that's it. There is nothing to save after the search algorithm completes. So there is no point in having a class.

But suppose you had a scenario where there is some reason to save state. For example, suppose you're doing multiple searches on the same array, where you have reason to believe that the results from consecutive searches will often be close together in the array. You might want to save the result of each search so you can start the next one by searching nearby indices. That's a case when you would want to use a class. In that case, you can distinguish option 3 from the others based on whether the stored state (in this case, the previous result) is relevant to all your algorithms. If all algorithms can make use of the same saved state, it probably makes sense to have one class with multiple search methods, and just choose the best search method by default, but allowing client code to pick the method if they so choose - that'd be something like a combination of option 1 and option 2.

```
def search(self, element, kind='binary'):
    if kind == 'binary':
        return self.binary_search(element)
    elif kind == 'linear':
        return self.linear_search(element)
    else:
        # error
def binary_search(self, element):
    ...
def linear_search(self, element):
    ...
```

But if different algorithms need different saved state, that's where you might want to use subclasses, or generally, different classes for different algorithms.

I'd say it makes sense to use a generic `search()` method rather than, or at least in addition to, specific search methods for individual algorithms (like `binary_search()` and `linear_search()`) because in many cases, you know which algorithm will be best and can choose that one. The only reason  I can think of not to provide a generic method in that sense is if you really cannot tell which algorithm to use, if different algorithms will be required in different situations, and you need to make client code choose which one to use.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. I think I have an example of where there would be saved state. Should I edit my question to reflect the new example or is that too big of an edit?

Comment: I'm not really sure. It would have been better if you'd written the question to reflect a more realistic example in the first place, but now that you've gotten an answer, it's probably better to leave the question as is - or at least, don't edit it in a way that invalidates the existing answer. (This is general etiquette, I'm not just saying so because I wrote the answer.) If you can edit in a way that uses your new example but without rendering my answer inapplicable, go for it.